# Audio Editor app in qt mobile

Tags: c++, qt, audio, qt5

I’m new to QT Development and so far enjoying it very much. I have already tried building some basic apps and now want to make something advanced.
I want to build a mobile app that will play an audio file, and i want to remove/edit some parts of that audio.

For example, if its a 1 minute song, i could press a button to start cutting from 15 second and then press it to stop on 30 second and then press to start cutting on 50 second and stop on 5 seond, which means i get final edited audio file of 15+5 = 20 seconds.

Please advise how can I approach it?

Thanks

Comment: start with a code that plays the whole file and share the code

Comment: MediaPlayer {

          id: mediaplayer

          source: "audios/InfluencerMarketing.mp3"

}